# Python program to divide one group to sub-groups with exceptions

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, sorting, group-by

I want to write a python code to divide a group consist of several rows to sub-groups depending on specific criteria to the effect that every row can join a group contain certain rows, but not permitted to join groups contain other rows.
for example:

```
Group_A =[
[[2, 3, 5, 6, 8], [1, 4, 7, 9], 0],
[[3, 4, 7, 8, 9], [0, 2, 5, 6], 1],
[[0, 3, 7, 8, 9], [1, 4, 5, 6], 2],
[[0, 1, 4, 7, 9], [2, 5, 6, 8], 3],
[[1, 5, 6, 8, 9], [0, 2, 3, 7], 4],
[[0, 2, 4, 7, 9], [1, 3, 6, 8], 5],
[[0, 4, 7, 8, 9], [1, 2, 3, 5], 6],
[[2, 3, 5, 6, 8], [0, 1, 4, 9], 7],
[[0, 2, 4, 7, 9], [1, 3, 5, 6], 8],
[[2, 3, 4, 6, 8], [0, 1, 5, 7], 9]]
```

Output:

```
Group_1 = [
[[2, 3, 5, 6, 8], [1, 4, 7, 9], 0]
[[1, 5, 6, 8, 9], [0, 2, 3, 7], 4]
[[2, 3, 5, 6, 8], [0, 1, 4, 9], 7]]

Group_2 = [
[[3, 4, 7, 8, 9], [0, 2, 5, 6], 1]
[[0, 3, 7, 8, 9], [1, 4, 5, 6], 2]
[[0, 4, 7, 8, 9], [1, 2, 3, 5], 6]]

Group_3 = [
[[0, 1, 4, 7, 9], [2, 5, 6, 8], 3]
[[0, 2, 4, 7, 9], [1, 3, 6, 8], 5]
[[0, 2, 4, 7, 9], [1, 3, 5, 6], 8]]

Group_4 = [[[2, 3, 4, 6, 8], [0, 1, 5, 7], 9]]
```

For more illustration:
For the first row [[2, 3, 5, 6, 8], [1, 4, 7, 9], 0], 0 is the number of the row, [2, 3, 5, 6, 8] the group contains rows 2,3,5,6 and 8 that row number 0 not permitted to join, but can join a group contain most of these rows[1, 4, 7, 9].

Another example as follows:

```
Group_B = [
[[1, 3, 6, 7, 9], [2, 4, 5, 8], 0]
[[0, 2, 4, 5, 8], [3, 6, 7, 9], 1]
[[0, 1, 4, 7, 8], [3, 5, 6, 9], 2]
[[0, 1, 4, 5, 8], [2, 6, 7, 9], 3]
[[2, 3, 7, 8, 9], [0, 1, 5, 6], 4]
[[1, 3, 6, 7, 9], [0, 2, 4, 8], 5]
[[0, 1, 5, 7, 8], [2, 3, 4, 9], 6]
[[0, 4, 5, 6, 8], [1, 2, 3, 9], 7]
[[1, 4, 6, 7, 9], [0, 2, 3, 5], 8]
[[0, 4, 5, 7, 8], [1, 2, 3, 6], 9]]
```

Output:

```
Group_1 = [
[[0, 1, 4, 7, 8], [3, 5, 6, 9], 2]
[[0, 1, 4, 5, 8], [2, 6, 7, 9], 3]
[[0, 1, 5, 7, 8], [2, 3, 4, 9], 6]
[[0, 4, 5, 7, 8], [1, 2, 3, 6], 9]]

Group_2 = [
[[1, 3, 6, 7, 9], [2, 4, 5, 8], 0]
[[1, 3, 6, 7, 9], [0, 2, 4, 8], 5]
[[1, 4, 6, 7, 9], [0, 2, 3, 5], 8]]

Group_3 = [
[[0, 2, 4, 5, 8], [3, 6, 7, 9], 1]
[[0, 4, 5, 6, 8], [1, 2, 3, 9], 7]]

Group_4 = [[[2, 3, 7, 8, 9], [0, 1, 5, 6], 4]]
```

Regards,

Comment: In the first example, why not join rows 0 and 9?

Comment: Row 9 in condition that, it must not join group contain rows [2, 3, 4, 6, 8], so group_1 that row 0 is a member of contains row number 4. Thus, row number 9 cannot join group_1. But you can remove row 0 from group_1 and join it to group_4 with row 9. but it's preferred any group take its maximum size in order to make a few groups as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My approach uses itertools to iterate over possible combinations

```
import itertools

Group_A =[
[[2, 3, 5, 6, 8], [1, 4, 7, 9], 0],
[[3, 4, 7, 8, 9], [0, 2, 5, 6], 1],
[[0, 3, 7, 8, 9], [1, 4, 5, 6], 2],
[[0, 1, 4, 7, 9], [2, 5, 6, 8], 3],
[[1, 5, 6, 8, 9], [0, 2, 3, 7], 4],
[[0, 2, 4, 7, 9], [1, 3, 6, 8], 5],
[[0, 4, 7, 8, 9], [1, 2, 3, 5], 6],
[[2, 3, 5, 6, 8], [0, 1, 4, 9], 7],
[[0, 2, 4, 7, 9], [1, 3, 5, 6], 8],
[[2, 3, 4, 6, 8], [0, 1, 5, 7], 9]]


Group_B = [
[[1, 3, 6, 7, 9], [2, 4, 5, 8], 0],
[[0, 2, 4, 5, 8], [3, 6, 7, 9], 1],
[[0, 1, 4, 7, 8], [3, 5, 6, 9], 2],
[[0, 1, 4, 5, 8], [2, 6, 7, 9], 3],
[[2, 3, 7, 8, 9], [0, 1, 5, 6], 4],
[[1, 3, 6, 7, 9], [0, 2, 4, 8], 5],
[[0, 1, 5, 7, 8], [2, 3, 4, 9], 6],
[[0, 4, 5, 6, 8], [1, 2, 3, 9], 7],
[[1, 4, 6, 7, 9], [0, 2, 3, 5], 8],
[[0, 4, 5, 7, 8], [1, 2, 3, 6], 9]]


def getGroups(groups):
    used = []
    c = 3
    group_c = 0
    print()
    while len(used) < 10:
        for x in range(0,10):
            for combo in itertools.combinations(groups[x][1], c):
                result = []
                for group in groups:
                        if group[2] not in used and group[2] in combo and x not in group[0]:
                            if (all(elem not in group[0] for elem in combo)):
                                result.append(group)
                
                if len(result) == c:
                    group_c += 1
                    print("GROUP", group_c)
                    
                    if x not in used:
                        print(groups[x])
                    for treffer in result:
                        print(treffer)
                        used.append(treffer[2])
                    used.append(x)
        c = c-1

getGroups(Group_A)

getGroups(Group_B)
```

The output looks as hopefully expected:

```
GROUP 1
[[2, 3, 5, 6, 8], [1, 4, 7, 9], 0]
[[1, 5, 6, 8, 9], [0, 2, 3, 7], 4]
[[2, 3, 5, 6, 8], [0, 1, 4, 9], 7]
GROUP 2
[[3, 4, 7, 8, 9], [0, 2, 5, 6], 1]
[[0, 3, 7, 8, 9], [1, 4, 5, 6], 2]
[[0, 4, 7, 8, 9], [1, 2, 3, 5], 6]
GROUP 3
[[0, 1, 4, 7, 9], [2, 5, 6, 8], 3]
[[0, 2, 4, 7, 9], [1, 3, 6, 8], 5]
[[0, 2, 4, 7, 9], [1, 3, 5, 6], 8]
GROUP 4
[[2, 3, 4, 6, 8], [0, 1, 5, 7], 9]

GROUP 1
[[0, 1, 4, 7, 8], [3, 5, 6, 9], 2]
[[0, 1, 4, 5, 8], [2, 6, 7, 9], 3]
[[0, 1, 5, 7, 8], [2, 3, 4, 9], 6]
[[0, 4, 5, 7, 8], [1, 2, 3, 6], 9]
GROUP 2
[[1, 3, 6, 7, 9], [2, 4, 5, 8], 0]
[[2, 3, 7, 8, 9], [0, 1, 5, 6], 4]
[[1, 3, 6, 7, 9], [0, 2, 4, 8], 5]
GROUP 3
[[1, 4, 6, 7, 9], [0, 2, 3, 5], 8]
GROUP 4
[[0, 2, 4, 5, 8], [3, 6, 7, 9], 1]
[[0, 4, 5, 6, 8], [1, 2, 3, 9], 7]
```

Answer (score 0):

The following procedures and codes may help to solve the problem, but still something wrong with the code.

remove columns in the middle and join row number with the rest.
As in example number one:

```
Group_A =[
 [2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 0],
 [3, 4, 7, 8, 9, 1],
 [0, 3, 7, 8, 9, 2],
 [0, 1, 4, 7, 9, 3],
 [1, 5, 6, 8, 9, 4],
 [0, 2, 4, 7, 9, 5],
 [0, 4, 7, 8, 9, 6],
 [2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 7],
 [0, 2, 4, 7, 9, 8],
 [2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 9]]
```

then sort it with:

```
 group = group[np.lexsort([group[:, i] for i in (range(0, group.shape[1] - 1))])][::-1]
```

the result:

```
Group_A =[
 [3, 4, 7, 8, 9, 1],
 [0, 4, 7, 8, 9, 6],
 [0, 3, 7, 8, 9, 2],
 [1, 5, 6, 8, 9, 4],
 [0, 2, 4, 7, 9, 8],
 [0, 2, 4, 7, 9, 5], 
 [0, 1, 4, 7, 9, 3],
 [2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 7],
 [2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 0], 
 [2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 9]]
```

the code for grouping as follows:

```
def create_grouping(Group_A):
   temp1 = []  
   temp2 = []
   result = []
   size = len(group[0])
   for index in range(len(group) - 1):
        if group[index][size - 1] in group[index + 1] or len(set.intersection(set(group[index]), set(temp2))) > 0:
             temp1.append(group[index])
             result.append(temp1)
             temp1 = []
             temp2 = []
        else:
             temp2.append(group[index][size - 1])           
             temp1.append(group[index])

   print(" Result:", result)
   return
```

when running: create_grouping(Group_A)
I get output:

```
Result: [[array([3, 4, 7, 8, 9, 1]), array([0, 4, 7, 8, 9, 6]), array([0, 3, 7, 8, 9, 2]), array([1, 5, 6, 8, 9, 4])], [array([0, 2, 4, 7, 9, 8]), array([0, 2, 4, 7, 9, 5]), array([0, 1, 4, 7, 9, 3])]]
```

As shown the last groups not created, and groups items not accurate.  something missing in the code.